# How to access an index in a queue

Tags: python, indexing, queue

I'm using a queue in python to push the tasks that is supposed to be processed (I'm using the [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) class in python) I know that a queue has a FIFO behavior, but for load balancing purposes I need to transfer a number of items in the queue (from the end of the queue) to another processor.

For example, suppose I have 100 tasks in my queue, I want to transfer 80th to 100th items to another processor, so my question is: Is it possible to access a special index (for example 80th index) in a queue?

Comment: @helen Assuming that you are always transfering from the end of the queue, you could change your implementation to a double-ended queue.

Comment: @JETM No, I'm using the Python Queue class.

Comment: Is the head task of the queue equal to 1? If so, transferring 80th to 100th is not queue like structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to implement a stack or a queue in Python is to use a list.
If your class inherit the `list` type, you can acces any element using `instance_of_your_queue[79]`.

```
class Queue(list):
    def enqueue(self, obj):
        self.append(obj)
    def dequeue(self):
        return self.pop(0)   
q = Queue()
q.enqueue(0)
q.enqueue(1)
q.enqueue(Task())
q.dequeue()
# return 0
q[1]
#return the Task you created
```

EDIT: Ouch, you edited your post.

Comment: Thanks, yes of course it is possible by using a `list`, but I'm using Python Queue class and I wanted to know if it is possible using this class.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is also helpful.